# Is there a way in which a polynomial equation can be graphed via input()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I started learning Python a few months back (in 11th grade), and decided to test my knowledge by creating a miniature Graphing Calculator in Python. Using matplotlib.pyplot i was able to graph the sin(), cos(), and the tan(). Now, I wanted the user to enter a polynomial equation in terms of y, and then display the graph of the equation, but I am getting a Type Error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1) 
y = input("Enter polynomial equation in terms of y\ny = ") 
plt.plot(x, y) 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest), Python's symbolic math library, can be used to create a plot from a function inputted by the user:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sy
from sympy.abc import x

y = input("Enter equation in terms of x\ny = ")
sy.plot(sy.sympify(y), (x, -10, 10) )
plt.show()
```

When inputted "sin(x)/x":
[image: sin(x)/x]

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input("x^2 coefficient: ")
b = input("x^1 coefficient: ")
c = input("x^0 coefficient: ")

y = (a * (x * x)) + (b * x) + c

plt.plot(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Input is not evaluated automatically. There are good reasons for that. If you want to evaluate input you need to explicitely do it with `eval`

```
y = eval(input(...))
```

Hence,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1) 
y = eval(input("Enter polynomial equation in terms of y\ny = "))

plt.plot(x, y) 
plt.show()
```